# PHP Product Listing - End of Loop Close Row

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, lazy-loading, advanced-custom-fields

Sorry for the title, I wasn't sure how to word it.

Basically, I have a webpage that uses Advanced Custom Fields to populate products, it loops through the products and displays them in groups of three, per row; each row alternates color - light grey to dark grey.

My issue is, the code I wrote is checking if each row has 3 items, so if the product listing row ends on 1 or 2, the row containing div is not closed off, thus wrapping my footer and messing up the for the rest of the page. The following is my code, it should be pretty easy to follow - you can also see I am using LazyLoadAny - Basically, I count the items, if there are more than 6 I lazyload the rest. On the first item I open the row container and when there are three I close it. So again, I need to figure out how to close the container if the row ends on 1 or 2 items not just 3.

Short Version: How do I close the "internal-product-light" or "internal-product-dark" rows if they end with 1 or 2 products instead of 3?

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$rowCount = 0;
$rowClass = "internal-product-light";
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('product_listing_repeater') ): ?>
<div class="internal-container">
    <div class="full-product-line-contain">
        <?php // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('product_listing_repeater') ) : the_row(); $count++; $rowCount++; ?>
            <?php if($rowCount  == 1) { ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                <div class="product-centering">

                <?php if($count > 6) { ?>
                    <div class="js-lazyload">
                    <?php echo "<!--"; }
            } ?>
            <div class="internal-section product-line-item product-alignment clearfix">
                <div class="product-contain">
                    <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-link">
                            <?php
                            if(get_sub_field('has_image')):
                                $singleImage = get_sub_field('block_image');
                                ?>
                                <img class="product-line-image" src="<?php echo $singleImage ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="internal-content-contain-right no-float">
                        <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-link-title">
                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('block_headline'); ?></h2>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-line-btn"><?php the_sub_field('link_text')?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($rowCount == 3) { ?>
                <?php if($count > 6) { echo "-->"; ?>
                    </div><!-- End lazy load div -->
                <?php } ?>
                </div><!-- End product centering -->
                </div><!-- End row -->
                <?php $rowCount = 0;
                if($rowClass == "internal-product-light"){ $rowClass = "internal-product-dark";}else{$rowClass = "internal-product-light";}
            } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be better to scratch what you've done and start with `array_chunk()`

Comment: Thank you @Popnoodles, could you please give me an example? I will research array_chunk() but a sample would be much appreciated.

Comment: You chunk your items into rows (of 3), then iterate those rows (and then each item within), so all you have to count is how many items are in the row as you iterate. Only the last row may have less than three, but in any case you're closing the row.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user solved the question, and it's unlikely that it would be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the following code is actually a much simpler solution than I thought it would be - I will post the code then break it down.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$rowCount = 0;
$rowClass = "internal-product-light";
$rowInfo = get_sub_field('product_listing_repeater');
$fieldCount = count($rowInfo);
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('product_listing_repeater') ): ?>
<div class="internal-container">
    <div class="full-product-line-contain">
        <?php // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('product_listing_repeater') ) : the_row(); $count++; $rowCount++; ?>
            <?php
               if($rowCount  == 1) { ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                <div class="product-centering">

                <?php if($count > 6) { ?>
                    <div class="js-lazyload">
                    <?php echo "<!--"; }
            } ?>
            <div class="internal-section product-line-item product-alignment clearfix">
                <div class="product-contain">
                    <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-link">
                            <?php
                            if(get_sub_field('has_image')):
                                $singleImage = get_sub_field('block_image');
                                ?>
                                <img class="product-line-image" src="<?php echo $singleImage ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="internal-content-contain-right no-float">
                        <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-link-title">
                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('block_headline'); ?></h2>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if(get_sub_field('has_link')): ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url')?>" class="product-line-btn"><?php the_sub_field('link_text')?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($rowCount == 3 || $count == $fieldCount) { ?>
                <?php if($count > 6 || $count == $fieldCount) { echo "-->"; ?>
                    </div><!-- End lazy load div -->
                <?php } ?>
                </div><!-- End product centering -->
                </div><!-- End row -->
                <?php $rowCount = 0;
                if($rowClass == "internal-product-light"){ $rowClass = "internal-product-dark";}else{$rowClass = "internal-product-light";}
            } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added the variable `$fieldCount = count($rowInfo)` which counts the ACF repeater field. Then when I was originally checking for 3 products, I added an `OR` statement - `<?php if($rowCount == 3 || $count == $fieldCount) { ?>` and to the lazyload check - `<?php if($count > 6 || $count == $fieldCount) { echo "-->"; ?>`

This makes sure that if it is 3, it closes the div and if it is the end of the array (figured out through `count`), it closes the div.

Please post any questions for clarification.

Comment: Is that a thing? I figured this would be useful to someone down the line, thats why I answered it so the solution would be public knowledge. I know you have more rep and time here than me so I will do whatever is best practice. @Popnoodles

Answer (score 1):

Your last if-statment could be:

```
<?php if(($rowCount % 3) == 0) { ?>
    <?php if($count > 6) { echo "-->"; ?>
    </div><!-- End lazy load div -->
    <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- End product centering -->
    </div><!-- End row -->
    <?php if($rowClass == "internal-product-light"){ $rowClass = "internal-product-dark";}else{$rowClass = "internal-product-light";}
    } ?>
```

And then, after the while-block:

```
<?php if(($rowCount % 3) <> 0) { ?>
    <?php if($count > 6) { echo "-->"; ?>
    </div><!-- End lazy load div -->
    <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- End product centering -->
    </div><!-- End row -->
    <?php if($rowClass == "internal-product-light"){ $rowClass = "internal-product-dark";}else{$rowClass = "internal-product-light";}
    } ?>
```

The `x % y` returns the remainder of `x/y`.

Comment: I see now that you can omit the `if($rowClass...`-statment inside the `if(($rowCount % 3) <> 0)`, since that seems to be used only inside the while-statment.

I hope you get the point, though.

Comment: thanks for the response. Let me give it a shot and try to get it working. Thanks for your help and time - if I get it to work I will mark your answer, otherwise I will provide feedback.

Comment: That was definitely close, not 100% but got me nearer to a solution thank you. I will upvote but not select as answer until I figure it out completely. I will also post an edited copy if I get it working.

Comment: What was the problem? Did you change the first row in your while statement from `<?php if($rowCount  == 1) { ?>` to `<?php if(($rowCount % 3)  == 1) { ?>`?